# How to zip elements of a list based on a condition?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists, say:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

and

```
b = ['B/X', 'Y/C', 'A/Z']
```

How do I efficiently zip the lists together to get:

```
[('A', 'A/Z'), ('B', 'B/X'), ('C', 'Y/C')]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What if there is an element `A/B` and `B/C` in `b`. Which element do you pick then?

Comment: There definitely isn't. That's why I didn't write those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply first construct a dictionary:

```
lookup = { ki : k for k in b for ki in k.split('/') }
```

and then use list comprehension:

```
[(k,lookup.get(k)) for k in a]
```

This will add `None` as second element in the tuple if no element of `b` had a subelement that matched. It will generate:

```
>>> [(k,lookup.get(k)) for k in a]
[('A', 'A/Z'), ('B', 'B/X'), ('C', 'Y/C')]
```